# Invoking my own plugin in another java project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I've developed a plugin (MultiTanPluginX) that executes a m2m QVT transformation. The transformation is executed successfully in the plugin itself, however, when exporting the plugin and using it in another java project I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.compiler.UnitResolverFactory$Registry
    org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.TransformationExecutor.doLoad(TransformationExecutor.java:205)
    org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.TransformationExecutor.loadTransformation(TransformationExecutor.java:108)
    org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.TransformationExecutor.execute(TransformationExecutor.java:137)
    multitenantplugin.qvtTransform.generateMultiTenant(qvtTransform.java:81)
    org.saas.mda.tenanthandler.tenantServlet.dothistrans(tenantServlet.java:205)
    org.saas.mda.tenanthandler.tenantServlet.doGet(tenantServlet.java:182)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I've defined this class in the Runtime plugins inside my plugin, however, this class can't be included as a jar file in my new java project. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the `Registry` inner class of `org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.compiler.UnitResolverFactory`?

Comment: how can I access the registry inner class?

Comment: I don't know. Is this that class your code? For some reason it can't be found.

Comment: Here is the org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.compiler.UnitResolverFactory class and there is a registery instantiated inside it: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5.2/org.eclipse.m2m.qvt/oml/2.0.1/org/eclipse/m2m/internal/qvt/oml/compiler/UnitResolverFactory.java

Comment: Most Eclipse plugins can only be used in an Eclipse RCP and not in a normal Java program - it looks like your plugin falls in to that category.

Comment: No, it is not a class of my code, it is a package that I included in [Runtime/Exported packages] in my plugin project.

Comment: Can I use  Eclipse RCP to develop a J2EE web application and then include my plugin there?

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about J2EE

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate your help. I'll try to learn more about Eclipse RCP and got back to you If it works!

Comment: Yes. It worked! can you please add it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Eclipse plugins can only be used in an Eclipse RCP and not in a normal Java program because they rely on the Eclipse plugin infrastructure being initialized properly by the RCP startup code. It looks like your plugin falls in to that category.

So you need to use an Eclipse RCP.